# Which is faster mongodb query by using mongoose with condition or not?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Suppose I have users more than 300k and want to get users whose age is 30. Which is faster way to get specific users? 1 or 2?

```
// 1. Query all users and filter the users in local
User.find()
.then(function(users) {
    var myUsers = _.filter(users, { 'age': 30 });   
    // do something..
});


// 2. Query users with condition age = 30
User.find({age: 30})
.then(function(myUsers) {
    // do something..
});
```

Comment: Did you try them and measure?

Comment: Yes. It takes almost same time because I have not enough datas yet for performance testing. But I want to prevent the query to be slow in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always to do filter or sorting data when querying itself.

The problem with 1 is that when the data scales up and becomes huge. While executing the filter, all the RAM get consumed and starts to cause bottle necking

Comment: Thanks! You're right. Then what about just in terms of query performance without filtering? I guess the way to get all users is faster than query with some condition.

Answer (score 1):

use `lean: true` in mongoose then find

```
// 2. Query users with condition age = 30
User.find({age: 30},{},{lean:true})
.then(function(myUsers) {
    // do something..
});
```

> here is the link of the blog for [more
>   explanation](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/high-performance-find-query-using-lean-in-mongoose-2/)